# Flask: вернуть ответ и продолжить выполнение

Tags: python, flask

Есть ресурсоемкая задача, которую может вызвать пользователь.
Хочется ему вначале ответить "processing started"
А уже потом вернуть результат ее выполнения.

Как такое можно реализовать?
Читал про `after_request` и `teardown_request`, но кажется ответ отправляется только после их выполнения

Comment: Celery. . . . .

Comment: В моем случае нельзя запустить поток?

Comment: Ни в каком веб-сервере на питоне нельзя запускать потоки, это может сломать веб-сервер (есть исключения, но вас они пока не касаются)

Comment: можно, но вы ограничиваете способы развёртывания вашего веб-приложения. Попробуйте очередь задач (такие как celery, RQ, Huey, etc).

Comment: @andreymal, я верно понимаю, что если у меня нет бд, то я не смогу работать с Celery?

Comment: @user277248 не совсем, для общения с Celery используется RabbitMQ и Redis, первый вообще не бд, второй не совсем обычный бд, по идее для вас не должно быть большой проблемой установить что-нибудь из этого. А вообще это очень странно, если у вас нет бд :)

Comment: @andreymal полностью согласен:) еще очень странно, что на компьютере у меня Windows, а сервер работает на Linux

Comment: @andreymal, нельзя потоки запускать из-за GIL? А есть пруфы? А то у фласка при запуске можно обработку и на потоки, и на процессы отправлять и нормально: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823968/5909792

Comment: @gil9red про GIL я не говорил ни слова. Если вы попытаетесь запустить свой поток на каких-нибудь gunicorn или apache2-mod-wsgi, которые сами по себе могут запускать по 4 воркера и 8 потоков в каждом - ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет. А gunicorn ещё и может прибивать воркеры по таймауту или лимиту числа запросов, это задокументированная фича

Comment: @gil9red и ни один нормальный человек не будет выкатывать дебаг-сервер фласка на продакшен, так что ваша ссылка бесполезна чуть более чем полностью. Хотя чего это я - по вашей ссылке тоже нет запуска СВОИХ потоков - всеми потоками управляет фласк независимо от вас. Речь вообще не об этом.